# Regex: In a group defined by boundries, only match if XX

Tags: regex

Context: I'm trying to filter some logs I have, and I can't change the way they are generated. What they look like is basically:

```
Some text here AAA
Some text here One
Some More text here
******
Some text here BBB
Some text here Two
Some More text here
******
Some text here CCC
Some text here Three
Some More text here
******
Some text here BBB
Some text here Four
Some More text here
******
Some text here BBB
Some text here Five
Some More text here
******
```

And basically, every `******` delimits a new log *event*.

I'm trying to get a regex to match every block that resides between two `******` that contains, for example `BBB`. (I know the first one doesn't start with `******`, but I'm fine with not matching that one for complexity sake)

What I tried to do was basically "Define a potential match with something delimited by `******` but doesn't have another `******`in between", but I don't know how to write that. So in the aforementioned example, it would match the blocks that contains Two, Four and Five.

I tried multiple variations of things like:  `\*{6}(?!\*{6}).*BBB.*\*{6}`

Any tips?

**Edit**: The regex version I'm using is PCRE (php) in Notepad++/VisualStudio and Regex101.com.

Comment: What is your regex flavor/tool?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++, so mostly pcre, but I'm also testing using regex101.com (pcre). I can do it in VS if needed.

Comment: `^[^*]+\bB{3}\b[^*]+$` is what you are really looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in PCRE:

```
(?:\A|\*{6})(?:(?!\*{6}).)*?BBB.*?(?=\R\*{6})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0NfsB/1)

**RegEx Detail:**

- `(?:\A|\*{6})`: Match start or `******`
- `(?:(?!\*{6}).)*?`: Match 0 or more characters that don't have `******` ahead of them
- `BBB.*?`: Match `BBB` followed by 0 or more characters
- `(?=\R\*{6})`: Using lookahead assert that we have `******` at next position

Comment: Thanks sir, that's great! I adapted it to my concrete case and it does a marvelous job. I'll experiment with it just to make sure I understand it well so next time I'll know! :-D

Comment: You need to be careful of the `BBB` since the way you wrote your regular expression, any text  that has B that is unbounded might be included

Comment: If `BBB` is a complete word then replace `BBB` with `\bBBB\b`

Answer (score 2):

What you need:

```
^[^*]+\bB{3}\b[^*]+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/azHZJn/1)

This states:

- `^` asserts that begin at the start of a line
- `[^*]+` followed by many characters that are not `*`
- `\bB{3}\b` match three B's that are bounded.
- `[^*]+` followed by many characters that are not `*`
- `$` End the line

Comment: @UnbearableLightness am quite not sure whether that needs to be captured since OP stated that OP wanted to match the texts `inbetween` ... so that was my concern although we can use `^[*]{6}[^*]+\bB{3}\b[^*]+` to match the 6 stars

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(?<=\*{6}\s)(?=.*B{3})[^(?>\*{6})]+`.

It uses positive lookbehind to match six stars followed by whitespace (for example new line, you could also use `\n` as well): `(?<=\*{6}\s)`.

Then, it uses positive lookahead to make sure following text contains `BBB`: `(?=.*B{3})`.

Then, it captures everything until next six dots, thanks to set, that excludes occurence of six stars (because I made it as atomic `(?>\*{6})`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/juQEEx/2)

Comment: It's not atomic, you put the `*` into the negated class which let's it stop. As well [`\*{6}[^*]*BBB[^*]*`](https://regex101.com/r/juQEEx/3) could be used, if there's no `*` inside the block. Further this would not match `BBB` if occuring in the first block that's not preceded by `******`